# Incorrect ctags called from OS X command line

Tags: macos, bash, path, osx-mavericks, ctags

I'd like to use exuberant ctags. However, on OS X 10.9, the default seems to be to call a different binary,
          `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/ctags`

I can easily obtain exuberant ctags from MacPorts with 
    `sudo port install ctags`
and my path seems to be set correctly to allow use of the new binary in `/opt/local/bin` (the first location in my path)

```
$ which ctags
/opt/local/bin/ctags
```

However, executing `ctags` still calls the version inside `XCode.app`. I can of course use 
    `which ctags` 
and call the correct binary with its full path, but I'm confused as to why the path doesn't seem to be working like it should.

Why does the result of `which` not actually specify which binary will be executed in this case?

**Update**: Starting a new bash shell resolved the issue. Presumably the name of the executable was cached somewhere, but how can I prevent this from happening in the future?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't *prevent* the shell from caching the location of commands; this is generally done for performance reasons.  However, you *can* force the shell to refresh this cache on demand.  With `bash`, the `hash` command can be used to manipulate this command cache.  Running:

```
hash mycommand
```

Will cause the shell to update the stored location for `mycommand`.  For example, if my `$PATH` starts with:

```
$HOME/bin/A:$HOME/bin/B
```

And I put a sell script called `mycommand` in $HOME/bin/B:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo This is B.
```

And then run `mycommand`, I get:

```
$ mycommand
This is B.
```

If I then create a script of the same name in `$HOME/bin/A`:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo This is A.
```

And then run `mycommand`, we see that `bash` is using the cached location:

```
$ mycommand
This is B.
```

If I then use the `hash` command, we see the `bash` updates the location:

```
$ hash mycommand
$ mycommand
This is A.
```

Changing your `PATH` environment variable will also cause `bash` to forget about the cached location of binaries.